# ¿Como debo usar define en c++? me marca error y ya revise mi código bastante

Tags: c++

```
#define sumar (a,b) a+b
#define restar (a,b) a-b
#define multiplicar (a,b) a*b
#define dividir (a,b) a/b
#include <iostream>

    int numero1= 11;
    int numero2= 22;

    int suma;
    int resta;
    int multi;
    int divid;
    using namespace std;
    int main ()
            {
            suma= sumar (numero1 , numero2);
            resta= restar (numero1 , numero2);
            multi= multiplicar (numero1 , numero2);
            divid=  dividir (numero1 , numero2);

                cout << "la suma de 11 y 22 es:" << suma << endl;
                cout << "la resta de 11 y 22 es:" << resta << endl;
                cout << "la multiplicacion de 11 y 22 es:" << multi << endl;
                cout << "la division de 11 y 22 es:" << divid << endl;

            cin.get();
            return 0;

            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Ya que estás en C++... **No** uses `#define` salvo que sea necesario... lo cual relega su uso como guarda de las cabeceras y poco más:

```
#ifndef CABECERA_HPP
#define CABECERA_HPP

// ...

#endif CABECERA_HPP
```

En su lugar usa funciones `inline`. Son más seguras por varias razones:

- Poseen un tipado fuerte (lo que permite detectar errores)
- Se pueden depurar (las macros no)
- Evitan errores tontos. ¿Qué devuelve el siguiente programa?

  ```
  #define MENOR(a,b) (a>b)?b:a;

  int main()
  {
    int a = 2, b = 3;
    std::cout << MENOR(a++,b++);
  }
  ```

  ¿Y este otro?

  ```
  inline int menor(int a, int b)
  { return (a>b)? b : a;

  int main()
  {
    int a = 2, b = 3;
    std::cout << menor(a++,b++);
  }
  ```

Además las funciones inline no suponen una penalización por rendimiento (o no tiene por qué suponerlo). Son el sustituto *antiguo* de C++ para las macros.

En tu caso el problema es que los parámetros de las macros tienen que definirse pegados al nombre de la macro... sin espacios:

```
#define sumar(a,b) a+b
```

Y lo mismo con las demás... aunque yo personalmente preferiría usar, como he dicho, funciones inline:

```
inline int sumar(int a, int b)
{ return a+b; }

inline int restar(int a, int b)
{ return a-b; }

inline int multiplicar(int a, int b)
{ return a*b; }

inline int dividir(int a, int b)
{ return a/b; }
```

Comment: Algunos aconsejan usar los `#define` en otros contextos, como por ejemplo [simplificar el código de punteros a funciones](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#macro-for-ptr-to-memfn).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster por eso he dicho *"... y poco más"*

Comment: Y yo añado un ejemplo de ello, ahí queda para la posteridad :)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster jajajaja. No he puesto ejemplos porque cada caso es un mundo y se podrían encontrar otros tantos usos en los que `#define` es incluso imprescindible (acuérdate de lo que hicimos con `if constexpr` para importar nombres... pero sí creo que es importante relegar su uso al mínimo imprescindible

Answer (score 1):

Te aconsejo poner la *directiva de preprocesador* al principio del archivo como buena práctica. Los macros que defines no deben contener espacios en los parámetros, dejando el código de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>

#define sumar(a,b) a+b
#define restar(a,b) a-b
#define multiplicar(a,b) a*b
#define dividir(a,b) a/b

using namespace std;

    int numero1= 11;
    int numero2= 22;

    int suma;
    int resta;
    int multi;
    int divid;

    int main ()
            {
            suma= sumar (numero1 , numero2);
            resta= restar (numero1 , numero2);
            multi= multiplicar (numero1 , numero2);
            divid=  dividir (numero1 , numero2);

                cout << "la suma de 11 y 22 es:" << suma << endl;
                cout << "la resta de 11 y 22 es:" << resta << endl;
                cout << "la multiplicacion de 11 y 22 es:" << multi << endl;
                cout << "la division de 11 y 22 es:" << divid << endl;

            //cin.get(); Esta sentencia sirve para almacenar el primer caracter introducido por el teclado. Pero no es almacenado en ningún sitio, razon que lo he comentado
            return 0;

            }
```

Comment: ¿por que le llamas fichero a un archivo? un fichero es un .rar .zip

Comment: Gracias por la objeción @RenatoA. Arreglado ;)